# Python gettext fails to load translation file

Tags: python, gettext

**Problem:**

When loading a compiled translation file in python [gettext](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gettext.html) it throws the exception

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxxx.py", line 6, in <module>
    lang_en = gettext.translation(__appname__,LanguageDirectory,languages=['en'])
  File "C:\Python33\lib\gettext.py", line 410, in translation
    t = _translations.setdefault(key, class_(fp))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\gettext.py", line 160, in __init__
    self._parse(fp)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\gettext.py", line 265, in _parse
    item = b_item.decode().strip()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position xxx: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: ENCODING PROBLEMS! YAY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

The [gettext.py](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gettext.html) library currently doesn't parse iso-8859 characters in the header of the translation file.

Example Header with that problem (before compiled):

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR ORGANIZATION
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2013-12-06 11:22\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE+Mitteleuropäische Zeit\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=CHARSET\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: ENCODING\n"
"Generated-By: pygettext.py 1.5\n"
```

In this example `Mitteleuropäische Zeit` will cause the problem.

**How to fix**
Currently the easiest way to avoid this is not to use iso-8859 characters inside the header.
To prevent `pygettext.py` adding the timezone in your current language to the header you can change
Line 447 - pygettext.py

```
timestamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M-%Z')
```

to

```
timestamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', time.gmtime())
```

With this modification pygettext wont add the timezone to the header. Instead it will use the current [Greenwich Mean Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time)